# Society of Supercentenarians

Tags: story-identification

I read a sci-fi series where some of the main characters belonged to a society of the oldest people on the planet, where the oldest member was the chairman. Any ideas what it is called or who wrote something like this?

Answer (score 15):

I think that's [*Methusaleh's Children*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methuselah%27s_Children) by Robert Heinlein, though it could conceivably also be *Time Enough For Love* which uses the same background.

> The Howard Families derive from Ira Howard, who became rich in the
> California Gold Rush, but died young and childless. The trustees of
> his will carried out his wishes to prolong human life by financially
> rewarding those with long-lived grandparents, who married each other
> and had children. By the 22nd Century, these families have a life
> expectancy of 150 years, and have kept their existence secret, but
> reveal themselves to the society established under The Covenant, which
> refuses to believe that the Howard Families obtained their lifespan by
> selective breeding, instead insisting they have developed a secret
> method to extend life. Though the Administrator of the planet, Slayton
> Ford, is convinced the Families are telling the truth, he cannot
> prevent efforts to force the Howard Families to reveal their
> (non-existent) rejuvenatory abilities.

To quote from the text:

> Mary got out, said hello to the guards and went on through a tunnel
> into a large underground room where fifty or sixty men and women were
> seated. She chatted until a clock announced midnight, then she mounted
> a rostrum and faced them.
>
> "I am," she stated, "one hundred and eighty-three years old. Is there anyone here who is older?"
>
> No one spoke. After a decent wait she went on, "Then in accordance with our customs I declare this meeting opened. Will you
> choose a moderator?"

Comment: *Time Enough For Love* does more than just use "the same background" - it is for all intents and purposes the sequel to *Methusaleh's Children*.

Comment: @user14111 Yes, see the quote from the text that I included. Mary (Sperling) is chairing the meeting, because she's the oldest member present.

Answer (score 8):

Larry Niven's "Tales of the known space" have the Struldbrug club (named after the [immortal, but constantly aging people of Luggnagg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struldbrug) in Swift's Gulliver's Travels). One prominent character is a member (but not chairman) in some of the stories (namely in [Protector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protector_(novel))), the detective Lucas Garner.

> Not a single Struldbrug was less than one hundred and fifty-four years
>   of age, by Club law, and the age requirement went up one year for
>   every two that passed. They needed the best and most rigid of medical
>   protection.

The oldest member is (at least in name) head of the club:

> “No. Wait a minute. Estelle Randall? President of the Struldbrugs’
>   Club until — um.”
>
> “She was my great-to-the-fourth grandmother.”
>
> “And she died last month. My condolences.”
>
> “Thanks. I, I — see. I didn’t see Greatly ’Stelle that often. Maybe
>   twice a year, once at her birthday party, once at a christening or
>   whatever. I remember we had lunch together a few days after I found
>   out I’d lost all my money. She was mad. Oh, boy. She offered to
>   refinance me, but I turned her down.”
>
> “Pride? It could happen to anyone. Lawrence St. John McGee practices
>   an old and polished profession.”
>
> “I know.”
>
> “She was the oldest woman in the world.”
>
> “I know.” **The presidency of the Struldbrugs’ Club went to the oldest
>   living member**. It was an honorary title; the Acting President usually
>   did the work. “

Comment: Doesn't match the question very well, because the question says that several of the main characters belong to the society (Lucas Garner is the only main character who is a Struldbug), and because there's nothing to indicate that Struldbugs are chaired by the oldest member.

Comment: Actually it is specifically mentioned that the club is chaired by it's oldest member (Roy Truesdale's grandmother). I agree that it's very likely not a match, on the other hand there is not much to go on and people have misremembered details before.

Comment: Looks like a perfect match to me. The OP didn't say "several" (two or more), she said "some" which could be just one.

Comment: Yup, my memory of the details were a bit off. But Larry Niven's "Tales of the known space" was what I was looking for. Though I will definately look at the other suggestions. Thank you.